# Read a Text File in Same Folder With App

Tags: c#, file, stream, reader

I have a Windows Forms app. There is a text file in the same folder with the app.

I want to read this text file and write it in a rich text box. I tried several things but can't do it. What should I do?

Here is my solution explorer;

[image]

Here is my About.cs:

```
 private void About_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        aboutText.Enabled = false;
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        aboutText.Text = File.ReadAllLines(appPath + "TOSandAbout.txt").ToString();

    }
```

I can't read like this.

Comment: have you tried debugging? put a hard-coded path? check for your self what's in "appPath " before running this code..

Comment: What happens when you run the code?  Does it find the file?  I'm betting if it does it reads the file just fine, but then you see something like `System.Array[]` or something because of the `ToString()`.

Comment: yes i debugged it returns:
"C:\\Users\\fhatipoglu\\Desktop\\Spy\\Lightning\\Lightning.Transporter\\bin\\Debug"
but i'll upload this application. And it must be find the text file on other users. And text file will in same folder with app.

Comment: Your code `appPath + "TOSandAbout.txt"` will return `...Transporter\\bin\\DebugTOSandAbout.txt` not ``...Transporter\\bin\\Debug\\TOSandAbout.txt`` Use **`Path.Combine`**

Comment: Thank you all who answered me.
I got it. Ty. I tried publish app. And run. So it can read file with: string fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("TOSandAbout.txt"); but working in VS it can't read the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have VS on me at the moment, so no screenshots and I can't be sure of names, but the problem is because Visual Studio builds the source into a different directory (it's usually `bin/Debug/` or `bin/Release/` or something like that). Each file in the source directory has a behavior during the build process and I believe the default for `.txt` is "Do Not Copy". Open the Properties dialog for the file (`right click->Properties`) and where it says "Build Action", make sure it says "None" and then under "Copy to Output Directory" choose "Copy if Newer". This will make sure that the text file is actually alongside the executable when you build it (`Build Action: None` just means that there is no processing to be done on that file).

Comment: Full path for text file is "C:\Users\fhatipoglu\Desktop\Spy\Lightning\Lightning.Transporter\TOSandAbout.txt". But when other users install this program, it can't be in same location i think.

Comment: Well, yeah. That's why you tell Visual Studio to copy the file to the output directory, with the rest of the files (like the executable). If you look in that hidden `bin` folder in your solution, inside the `debug` folder inside that you'll see your compiled executable (which is what gets run when you run the program from VS), but not the text file. When you then try to load the file in the same directory, it can't find it.

Comment: Yep i got it. Ty. I tried publish app. And run. So it can read file with:
string fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("TOSandAbout.txt");
but working in VS it can't read the file.

Comment: Yep! Don't forget to mark it as the answer. ;P

Comment: i did it :) Ty again

Answer (score 1):

When a program starts the "current directory" will (usually) be set to the location of the exe. In that case, you do not have to specify any path, simply use `"TOSandAbout.txt"` as the path.

If that doesn't work, it's because the file isn't there. If you add a text file to your solution, it will by default *not* be copied to the build directory. Right click the file and hit Properties, change `Copy to Output Directory` to either `Copy always` or `Copy if newer` and you'll be set.

Comment: You'r right Chris. I did it. Ty so much everyone.